# android notification application not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

hello recently i started android application developer. so you can say i m a beginner level developer. i am trying to develop a basic notification application. this application right now capable to display notification but clicking on notification icon at the top of the virtual device nothing happened. the problem is that it should start a new activity named NotificationView but it is unable to start that.

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.notification1;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
   Button b1;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
      b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            Notify("You've received new message","");
         }
      });
   }
   private void Notify(String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage){
      NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

      Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"New Message", System.currentTimeMillis());
      Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,NotificationView.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,notificationIntent, 0);

      notification.setLatestEventInfo(MainActivity.this, notificationTitle,notificationMessage, pendingIntent);
      notificationManager.notify(9999, notification);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
      // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
      // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

      int id = item.getItemId();

      //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
      if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
         return true;
      }
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```

NotificationView.java

```
   package com.example.notification1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class NotificationView extends Activity{
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.notification);
   }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.notification1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NotificationView"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context="MainActivity">

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Notification Example"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:textSize="30dp" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Tutorials point "
      android:textColor="#ff87ff09"
      android:textSize="30dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="48dp" />

   <ImageButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/imageButton"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="42dp" />

   <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Notification"
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

notification.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="400dp"
      android:text="Hi, Your Detailed notification view goes here...." />
</LinearLayout>
```

here is the logcat data during clicking on the notification icon

```
11-19 06:05:44.924: I/Choreographer(1214): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-19 06:05:44.955: V/PanelView(1271): animationTick called with dtms=0; nothing to do (h=0.19166172 v=0.0)
11-19 06:05:44.955: I/Choreographer(1271): Skipped 152 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-19 06:05:45.004: V/PanelView(1271): animationTick called with dtms=0; nothing to do (h=0.04166171 v=-1500.0)
11-19 06:05:45.014: V/PanelBar(1271): onTouch: no panel for touch at (14,11)
11-19 06:05:45.024: I/Choreographer(1271): Skipped 69 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-19 06:05:45.054: I/Choreographer(1214): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-19 06:05:45.084: I/Choreographer(1271): Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-19 06:05:45.154: W/InputMethodManagerService(1214): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@b4e4dbd8 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@b4a95d50
11-19 06:05:45.164: I/Choreographer(1271): Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-19 06:05:45.174: I/Choreographer(1214): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-19 06:06:00.170: I/Choreographer(1271): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't make static notification ID. It's bad idea.

```
notificationManager.notify(9999, notification);
```

Create something like this, for example:

```
int notificationId = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```

It's always work for me. More info about notification with pendingIntent [example](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html#DirectEntry)

Let me know if it's will work for you ;)

Comment: It's look like you have to much instruction in onCreate method or runonUIThread. Please consider to make thread, runnable or AsyncTask for your long operations. Read more about this warning "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

Answer (score 0):

try to use NotificationCompat, you will have better support on different devices, I wrote about it: http://alexzh.com/tutorials/notification-for-android/

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for you. And make sure that you already compiled `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` in your `build.gradle` of the app's module.

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Intent intentNotif = new Intent(this, NotificationView.class);
intentNotif.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentNotif, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setOngoing(false)
                .setContentIntent(pendIntent)
                .setContentTitle("Title here")
                .setContentText("Notification content!")
                .setTicker("This is ticker!");

int id = 1234;
mNotificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and I was able to start `NotificationView` without having to change anything in your code.

I think you may have missed declaring `NotificationView` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. All activities must be declared in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. Your `AndroidManifest.xml` must look something like below:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NotificationView"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
</application>
```

`MainActivity` will be declared already, you just have to declare `NotificationView`. Hope this solves the issue in `<activity>` tag.

Comment: I am not sure if the logs that you posted pertains to your Application. Could you explain what is happening when you click on the notification? What version of Android OS are you testing in? Are you testing in emulator?

Comment: yes i m testing it on emulator in android 4.3.1. when i click on the notification icon nothing happen. it should launch the desired activity

Comment: I just tested with an emulator and it works even there. Are you clicking on the notification after swiping down on the status bar?